# What do the Semicolon and Identifier do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have just started to learn JavaScript from Lynda.com, and I am now working on the lesson about functions.

I am confused about the anonymous function.  When I wrote the code below my IDE showed some warnings which I don't understand.

```
var theBiggest = function(a,b) {
"use strict";
var result;
a>b ? result = ["a", a] : result = ["b", b];
console.log(result);    
})(5/7,18/25)

console.log(theBiggest);
```

The warnings are:

> 1). Missing semicolon on line 6 of code.
>
> 2). Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression on line 4.
>
> Expected an identifier and instead saw ')' on line 6.

The tutorial has same code as me but mine isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A semicolon is the ";" character which ends a statement. Normally, js doesn't really care wether you put a ; at the end of every statement, but because you use strict mode, you are obligated to put it there.

After the closing }-bracket on line six, I see a closing )-bracket, but its opening bracket is nowhere to be found. What you are doing here is an immediate function (function definition and a call to that function at the same time). Usually when using immediate functions, the whole function is surrounded by () brackets to make it clear you are actually calling the function and not assigning it to a variable (theBiggest in this case)

Comment: Well done for being the only person to mention that the semi-colon error is due to `use strict`. PS. they're commonly known as Immediately Invoked Function Expressions, not just Immediate Functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a closing bracket too much

```
})(5/7,18/25)
 ^
```

Beside that, I suggest to use the ternay as an assignment of the array.

```js
var theBiggest = function(a, b) {
    "use strict";
    var result = a > b ? ["a", a] : ["b", b];
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}(5 / 7, 18 / 25);

console.log(theBiggest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot open bracket before function :

```
var theBiggest = (function(a,b) {
"use strict";
var result;
a>b ? result = ["a", a] : result = ["b", b];
console.log(result);    
})(5/7,18/25)

console.log(theBiggest);
```

Comment: Nice spot but what about warning of missing semi colon is still there and what might is causing that and why.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Missing semicolon on line 6 of code.

Because you need to add a semicolon at the end of each expression (line) that is directly followed by another expression. So `(5/7,18/25)` should be `(5/7,18/25);`.

> 2. Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression on line 4.

Because you shouldn't use assignments in ternary operators , in fact, you should only use return values.

> 3. You have a closing bracket that isn't necessary, you also need to return the result.

```js
var theBiggest = function(a,b) {
    "use strict";
    var result = a>b ? ["a", a] : ["b", b];
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}(5/7,18/25);

console.log(theBiggest);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the things I see:

`result` needs to be assigned as the result of `a>b ? ["a", a] : ["b", b]`

You  have an extra `(` at the end of the function

The semicolon is the end of a statement that needs to be added in line 6 - after `(5/7,18/25)`.

The function needs to return  `result`

```js
 var theBiggest = function(a,b) {
    "use strict";
    var result;
    result = a>b ? ["a", a] : ["b", b];
    console.log(result);
    return result;
    }(5/7,18/25);
    
    console.log(theBiggest);
```